# How to grant sudo rights only to specific script files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, shell-scripting

I would like a user to have sudo rights (without password check) to a couple of shell scripts under a specific directory (in my case, `/usr/local/tomcat7/bin`), and to nowhere else. What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Something like this in `/etc/sudoers` didn't seem to work:

```
jsmith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/tomcat7/bin
```

Comment: Someone hopes these scripts and the directory are writable only by root since otherwise it's a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: I was searching for this, as I want a user to be able to execute a script using `sudo`, but NOT update the script. Making sure that the directory is writable only via sudo achieves this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you are almost there. put a `/` at the end of your directory spec

```
jsmith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/
```

From the sudoers man page

> A directory is a fully qualified path name ending in a '/'. When you
>   specify a directory in a Cmnd_List, the user will be able to run any
>   file within that directory (but not in any subdirectories therein).

Comment: Thanks (to both answerers), got it working! Note to self: need to invoke the scripts directly (e.g. `sudo catalina.sh stop`) - this doesn't work: `sudo sh catalina.sh stop`.

Answer (score 8):

Add a slash '/' to the end of the path.

```
jsmith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/
```