# How to set up SUDO rights for execution of Python script from PHP

Tags: php, debian, python, sudo

I run Raspbian Wheezy on my Raspberry Pi, and i want to call a `Python` script from `PHP`.
That all works great (i call '`exec python go.py`' from php) but now i want to call a script which needs root rights.

I understood that running as root would help me out here ('`exec sudo  python go2.py`', so i added this line of code to my sudo file

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

ok, and now it works again.
But then i learned that it is not a good idea to grant the www-data group unlimited sudo rights.
Then i found this question ([How to grant sudo rights only to specific script files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/294661/how-to-grant-sudo-rights-only-to-specific-script-files)), which showed me how to grant sudo rights to a single directory:

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/exec/
```

And then it all stops, because that doesn't work at my machine.

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

i'm using lighttpd as my webserver.

Comment: huh, why the -1, tell me, i might learn.

Comment: This is off-topic here (see the [FAQ]). It might fit on [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se], but check their FAQ and archives first.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't read the FAQ, thought it was for all kind of server related questions, not only for professionals. Didn't know about the Unix and Linux group, will try it there next time. The raspberry pi group off course was my first choice, but i thought this was more linux specific than Pi specific.

Answer (score 2):

The command you need to run with `sudo` is `python`, not `exec`, so try this:

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /path/to/the/go2.py
```

Comment: Ok, looks like i misunderstood things. I thought the `/var/www/exec/` part of my command stated that i allowed sudo rights for the group on the DIRECTORY `/var/www/exec/`. Is that not a correct assumption?

Comment: How should i read your proposed line ie what does this part `/usr/bin/python /path/to/the/go2.py` mean? Is it the combination of the path to a program and the path to the file here, so does it say "Yo can SUDO for python, for the file '/path/to/the/go2.py'?

Comment: About the first comment: No, `%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/exec/` allows all users in `www-data` group to run all commands in the `/var/www/exec/` as `sudo` without prompting for password. About the second: yes.

Comment: Will try it, will let you know wether it works

Comment: Hi, i ended up with this `%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /path/to/the/*` when i only typed the filename it didn't work. i checked it, and a .py file in the /path/to/ directory wasn't executed, and one in the /path/to/the/ folder was. Does that sound logical, the wild card character being necessary?